# An application created by me crashes since I updated the android version of my phone

Tags: android, android-studio

**I had created a multiple choice quiz game about a year ago and while creating it, I was using my personal phone to test it.**

After the latest significant update of the android version the application start stopping
*( I own an Oppo Reno with android version 11 and ColorOS version 11.1).*

While other applications (always created by me with Android Studio) work correctly instead this one stops abnormally. I do not understand what the problem is since at the code level I have not opened it since I finished it and precisely because other applications still work correctly.
The current version of Android studio is the **Bumblebee** and at the time I had the **ArticFox** version.

*The SDK version was always the same for the emulator in Android studio.*

---

I am a student and it was an application that it was rated positively (so it had no problems at the code level)

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these in your Android app module build.gradle in the android block with your appropriate versions:-

android{

compileSdkVersion 30

buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
}

If this doesn't work please checkout latest version and update.

For more go to : https://developer.android.com/studio/build

Comment: so I have to make these changes inside the build.gradle and then try to run the application on my phone again?

Comment: Yeah make the change and try again. And if the error not solved make the CompiledSdkVersion 30